# Magento 1.9.4 Session Error with PHP 7.2

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7.2

I upgrade PHP from 7.0 to 7.2 for magento 1.9.4.2 using redis session storage.
But it's tack much time for session connection and got below session errors in log file.

```
 1. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: __clone method called on
    non-object in
    /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php:214
 2. Warning: Unknown: Cannot call session save handler in a recursive
    manner  in Unknown on line 0
 3. Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: /var/lib/php/sessions)  in Unknown on line 0
```

I already use latest version of Cm_RedisSession & Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis.

Comment: magento 1.9 version requires PHP 5.4 (or 5.5). Try with it

Answer (score 0):

If i [remember](https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-1-official-php-7-2-patches/) right php7.2 support was added with v1.9.4.0, it should work.

You already asked there .... I'd suggest to upgrade to [OpenMage](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts) that definitely works with php7.2+ ;)

Comment: Yes it's working fine normally but when visitor > 1k than shown errors is there any idea about that?